# Where to download JDBC driver for oracle 7.3.4

Tags: oracle, jdbc

There is a Solaris VM with a Oracle 7.3.4 which I got from my customer. There isn't a jar file under ORACLE_HOME. I found all *.jar in the whole linux file system but didn't find the JDBC driver for Oracle.

The Oracle official site doesn't provide a JDBC driver for oracle 7.3.4. Do you know where I can download it?

Comment: I don't think Oracle 7 ever supported Java, from memory - classes11.zip or .jar was the first Java jdbc for Oracle 8, it might work. this might get you started http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A58617_01/server.804/a58237/toc.htm. Might be time to upgrade ;-)

Comment: oh yes it did http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A57673_01/DOC/server/doc/A56282_01/toc.htm

Comment: I thought there was a jdbc for Oracle 7 because of the web page http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A57673_01/DOC/server/doc/A56282_01/toc.htm. My project has distribute transaction requirement between Oracle 10 and Oracle 7. I use class111.jar(oracle8) to configure XA-Datasource in jboss EAP6, but it throw a error:  [com.arjuna.ats.jta] (Periodic Recovery) ARJUNA016009: Caught:: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Did you try a 8.x driver? I wouldn't be surprised if it was compatible with 7.x

Comment: Horse, yes! 8.x driver works fine on create/select operation for oracle7,but has error to create a XA-Datasource.

Comment: you could try the 9.01 driver its compatible with 7.3.4 and 10 http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-faq-090281.html#02_05

Comment: @GelnYang, could you please tell me where did you find the driver? I'm facing a similar issue as yours.

Comment: @PrasadKharkar，http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc817-100207.html